# Should I sign the UK visa application by hand?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am applying for a UK visa and when I printed the visa application, I noticed there are two blanks on the application:

1-APPLICANT'S SIGNATURE

2-DATE SIGNED

is it necessary to sign and date these blanks?

Answer (score 5):

A Document Checklist accompanies the Visa application, at the end of which there is a section that the applicant must sign and date when they are at the biometric appointment. The instructions clearly state NOT to sign the declaration until then.